# Explanation for checking Columns in Lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range, python-3.7

I am a beginner to Python and coding in general. I am trying to write a program for a basic TicTacToe game. I found some code online for finding vertical winners, but I am having difficulty understanding it. I understand what is happening when I am measuring the horizontal wins in the first for loop, but I do not understand what the for col in range(len(game)) is measuring and how it is different from the first for loop written for horizontal wins. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
game = [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]

def win(current_game):
    for row in game:
        if row.count(row[0]) == len(row) and row[0] != 0: 
            print("Winner")
    for col in range(len(game)):  
        check = []
        for row in game: 
            check.append(row[col])  
            if check.count(check[0]) == len(check) and check[0] != 0:
                print("Winner")
```

Comment: `for col in range(len(game))` means the loop iteartes from 0 to length of the game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `for` loop is looping through each row, counting how many times the first element appears, and printing `"Winner"` if that first value fills that row. The values that make up each row are neatly held inside their own list, so this is fairly simple.

The second `for` loop is doing the same thing, except it is looping through the columns, and checking to see if the same value fills any of those. This is a little more complicated because the values in a column are spread out across the lists that make up different rows. The second `for` loop constructs a temporary array called `check`, and then the third `for` loop (the one inside of the second) loops through each row, takes the value from that row that is in the current column, and appends that to the `check` list. Having added all of the values that make up a column to the same list makes it easy to check whether the first value in that column fills the entire column.

Also, the `if` statement inside of that third `for` loop should instead only  be inside the second `for` loop:

```
for col in range(len(game)):
    check = []
    for row in game:
        check.append(row[col])
    if check.count(check[0]) == len(check) and check[0] != 0:
        print("Winner")
```

Otherwise, once you find an element that isn't `0` in the first row of a column, the `check` array will only have one element in it and `check.count(check[0])` will equal `len(check)`, so it will print `"Winner"` without checking the rest of the elements in that column.